# Linux measuring time problem! std::chrono, QueryPerformanceCounter, clock_gettime

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, time-measurement

I use clock_gettime() in Linux and QueryPerformanceCounter() in Windows to measure time. When measuring time, I encountered an interesting case.

Firstly, I'm calculating DeltaTime in infinite while loop. This loop calls some update functions. To calculating DeltaTime, the program's waiting in 40 milliseconds in an Update function because update functions is empty yet.

Then, in the program compiled as Win64-Debug i measure DeltaTime. It's approximately 0.040f. And this continues as long as the program is running (Win64-Release works like that too). It runs correctly.

But in the program compiled as Linux64-Debug or Linux64-Release, there is a problem.

When the program starts running. Everything is normal. DeltaTime is approximately 0.040f. But after a while, deltatime is calculated 0.12XXf or 0.132XX, immediately after it's 0.040f. And so on.

I thought I was using QueryPerformanceCounter correctly and using clock_gettime() incorrectly. Then I decided to try it with the standard library std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, but it's the same. No change.

```
#define MICROSECONDS (1000*1000)

auto prev_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
decltype(prev_time) current_time;

while(1)
{
current_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

int64_t deltaTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(current_time - previous_time).count();

printf("DeltaTime: %f", deltaTime/(float)MICROSECONDS);

NetworkManager::instance().Update();

prev_time = current_time;

}
```

---

```
void NetworkManager::Update()
{
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
decltype(start) end;

while(1)
{
end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

int64_t y = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start).count();

if(y/(float)MICROSECONDS >= 0.040f)
break;

}

return;

}
```

[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbpeC.png)

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUp5t.png)

Comment: If you run your linux executable under strace does it show tons of system calls?

Comment: Rather than `(float)MICROSECONDS`, consider defining `MICROSECONDS` as a `float`. eg: `constexpr float MICROSECONDS = 1000*1000;`

Comment: `int64_t y = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start).count();` I'd personally use `auto` for `y` there. And `(float)MICROSECONDS` - eeek, *please* don't use C-style casts.

Comment: @bobah I've never used strace, but i'll try.

Comment: Unrelated: those images could be pasted text. Prefer text wherever possible as images are opaque to too many people.

Comment: @kmdreko Sorry, it must be 0.040f. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible causes:

1. Your clock_gettime is not using VDSO and is a system call instead - will be visible if run under `strace`, can be configured on modern kernel versions.
2. Your thread gets preempted (taken out of CPU by the scheduler). To run a clean experiment run your app with real time priority and pinned to a specific CPU core.

Also, I would disable CPU frequency scaling when experimenting.

Comment: What do you mean by real-time-priorty. Is it a thread priorty? I've never dealt with linux before. Why should a running program has taken out of CPU by the scheduler. I couldn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks, I'il take a look.

Comment: @bobah I tried it with 

"strace -p 9441 -e 'trace=!clock_gettime' -o /home/tgrl_monster_pc/strace.log"

There is just a write function. 

write(1, "DeltaTime: 0.040340 - 1567454514"..., 36) = 36. So It must be related to scheduling.

Comment: clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1567457330, 194450552}) = 0

Comment: @tgrlsrt - you can tell strace to also log how long a specific system call took. If you see `clock_gettime` in the strace output it means taking timestamps in your system can be quite expensive, usually you can change the OS config (exact instructions depends on the vendor) to use fast VDSO-based implementation (see [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Realtime_Tuning_Guide/sect-Realtime_Tuning_Guide-General_System_Tuning-gettimeofday_speedup.html) for example).

Comment: @bobah I pinned it to a specific cpu core.  No more problems. I'il take a look at VDSO. Thanks. Are there any disadvantages to enabling VDSO?

Comment: @tgrlsrt - it's accuracy vs call overhead trade-off (used to be few years back when I last worked with it)